# Add Header and Footer on all the pages except the first page?

Tags: python, docx, python-docx

Is there a way with the `python-docx` library to insert the header and footer on the whole document except on the first page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes:

```
section = document.sections[0]
section.different_first_page_header_footer = True
header = section.header
```

This setting is section-specific, so if you have more than one section in your document (most probably don't) then you'll need to set `.different_first_page_header_footer` to each section on which you want that behavior.

You can also access a distinct first-page header or footer after this using:

```
first_page_header = section.first_page_header
first_page_footer = section.first_page_footer
```